# API script function that makes a certain cell active works on a PC in chrome but not on the android sheets app where I need it to. Is there a fix?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Please note, I'm not a programmer and this is my first post on this site.  I cobbled this API script together by the seat of my pants by watching videos on YT and optimized it with some AI :-)

Here's my sheet that runs the script https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iWFj4JfSMmG0b3Pl5tM-3y5RY3FhOxhuyDGOFw7UE-g/edit?usp=sharing and below is the entire script.

On the mobile sheets app, when hitting the check box in cell B5, I want the SaveRecord function to execute (which it does) AND then I want the active cell to become B3. As I said in the title, this script below does exactly that on a PC in chrome but on the sheets app the active cell remains B5.

WHY!!?  And is there any way to modify this code so the selectCell function below (or some other code that does the same thing) executes on the sheets app?

Thanks! I will be extremely grateful if some kind soul would be able to assist with this, while keeping in mind I don't know how to program. :-)

```
function SaveRecord() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const formWS = ss.getSheetByName("FORM");
  const settingsWS = ss.getSheetByName("Settings");
  const dataWS = ss.getSheetByName("PRE-DATA");

  const SalesIDCell = formWS.getRange("F3");

  const fieldRange0 = ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "C4"];
  const fieldRange1 = ["B3", "B4", "C4"];
  
  const fieldValues = fieldRange0.map(f => formWS.getRange(f).getValue());
  const nextSalesIDCell = settingsWS.getRange("F3");
  const nextSalesID = nextSalesIDCell.getValue();

  // TO MOVE B1, B2, B3, B4 AND C4/5 TO PRE-DATA
  fieldValues.unshift(nextSalesID);
  dataWS.appendRow(fieldValues);

  // TO MAKE D HAVE LEADING ZEROS
  const lastRow = dataWS.getLastRow();
  const rangeD = dataWS.getRange("D3:D" + lastRow);
  rangeD.setNumberFormat("00000");

  // TO MAKE SALES ID VALUES GO UP BY ONE FOR THE DAY
  SalesIDCell.setValue(nextSalesID);
  nextSalesIDCell.setValue(nextSalesID + 1);

  // TO CLEAR CELLS B3,B4,C4/5
  fieldRange1.forEach(f => formWS.getRange(f).clearContent());
  SalesIDCell.clearContent();

  // Call the selectCell function to select the desired cell
  selectCell();
}

function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheetName = range.getSheet().getName();
  const cellAddress = range.getA1Notation();
  const activeValue = range.getValue();

  if (sheetName === "FORM" && cellAddress === "B5") {
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const formWS = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("FORM");
    range.setValue(false);
    SaveRecord();
  }

  if (sheetName === "FORM" && cellAddress === "D5") {
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const formWS = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("FORM");
    range.setValue(false);

    if (activeValue === true) {
      formWS.getRange("B1:B2").clearContent();
      range.setValue(false);
    }
  }
}

function selectCell() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getRange("B3");
  ss.setActiveRange(cell);
}

The selectCell function below works when called on a PC in chrome but not on the sheets app.

function selectCell() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getRange("B3");
  ss.setActiveRange(cell);`
```

Comment: 1) You have several sheets including: "FORM", "Settings", and "PRE-DATA". Which of these sheets do you intended that `selectCell()` should apply to. 2) `but on the sheets app the active cell remains B5` Would you please explain EXACTLY what you mean by "on the sheets app" **and**, (again, EXACTLY) how is this different from "on a PC in chrome".

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script runs on Google's servers, not in your end device.

UI methods such as `Spreadsheet.setActiveRange()` have no effect when you are editing a spreadsheet with the mobile Sheets app. These methods do work when editing a spreadsheet through a web browser, so one workaround is to access the spreadsheet through a web browser rather than through the app.

To create a user interface that works on the web and mobile alike, you can explore alternatives such as [web apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153205/269219) or [AppSheet](https://appsheet.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Unfortunately I need this form and script to run on a handheld, specifically a Zebra TC21 as we are using it in a warehouse like environment.   Perhaps there is another bit of code that would do the job on mobile and somebody will be able to help with that.   All I want is to make a certain cell the active cell.  I'm not asking for the moon here.

Comment: Nobody here can change the way the Sheets app works. You may want to explore alternatives. Added a couple of pointers in the answer.

Comment: Thanks again.  AppSheet looks interesting.  Starting over though... ugh.